# C: region-based memory management

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm looking for detailed description of memory management mechanisms for C applications, especially region-based memory management. I can't find any good in-depth articles/books/tutorials about it :(

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you seen the Cyclone system?

Comment: i didn't :( and googling it points me to weather or some stock resources =/ could you provide a link?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone_(programming_language)

Answer (score 2):

Good reference is the original Doom source code (zone memory allocator, see here http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Zone_memory)

Further development is Quake1 source code (hunk/zone malloc).

Not a tutorial, but a very nice implementation.

Comment: i know i can take a look at existing sources, such as nginx, doom, apache apr and etc... but the problem is it takes really lots of time and i can make a mistake while figuring out algorithm.

Comment: OK, I just thought that the linked list management (which is the heart of all those algorithms) is pretty classic. The first volume of Knuth's TAOCP is also a reference. Not much to say here :)

Comment: And I really mean you _should_ look there. It won't be the waste of a time if you trust me a little :)

Answer (score 0):

While not for C, I can say first handed that the implementation in the following paper is written in C, as a gcc-plugin.  The [paper here *PDF*](http://safari.ece.cmu.edu/MSPC2012/papers/p58-davis.pdf) is titled "Towards Region-Based Memory Management for Go."  There are plenty of semantics and such to explain how the authors implement RBMM for the Go programming language.

Comment: to my shame i didn't understand even a half... :(

Comment: Don't hesitate to email the authors if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is some information about [APR](http://apr.apache.org/)'s [memory pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool):

- A [chapter](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.developer.pools.html) from [Version Control with Subversion](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/index.html) book.
- A [chapter](http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial-3.html) from Inoue Seiichiro's [libapr programming tutorial](http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial.html).
- [Basic Resource Management in Apache: the APR Pools](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/pools), a tutorial.
- [API](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group__apr__pools.html).

Another example is [nginx](http://nginx.org/)'s pools which is basically [regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management):

- [ngx_palloc.h](https://github.com/git-mirror/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_palloc.h) (65 sloc).
- [ngx_palloc.c](https://github.com/git-mirror/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_palloc.c) (311 sloc).